# how to get data on arrays of values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have pairs of values `test_name`, `test_surname`.
How can I delete these rows from the table with one query. I assumed it could be done this way, but it can't be done this way.

```
DELETE FROM test_info
WHERE id_name = ($1::uuid[])
  AND id_surname = ($2::uuid[])
```

this is schema

```
create table test_info
(
    id_name    uuid not null,
    id_surname uuid not null,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of unnesting 2 arrays in one query (arrays must have the same size and dimension)

```sql
select unnest(array['1','2']),unnest(array['3','4']);
```

**Delete rows**

```sql
delete from test_info 
where 
 (id_name,id_surname) in (select unnest($1::uuid[]),unnest($2::uuid[]))
```